# shell scripting split the line into multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell

i have the following line list1/2/.. all are some strings with special characters

```
str=run -cmd 'list1' -cmd 'list2' -cmd 'list3' -cmd 'list4' -cmd 'list5' -cmd 'list6' -tail_cmd
```

required output multiple files

```
run -cmd 'list1'  -tail_cmd
run -cmd 'list2'  -tail_cmd
run -cmd 'list3'  -tail_cmd
run -cmd 'list4'  -tail_cmd
```

where can i start ?
i tried to use sed to split and populate the array but its ignoring the spaces in side the array
command which i tried

```
arr=(`echo $str | sed 's/ -cmd /\n -cmd /g'`)
```

plan to process the arr[0] and arr[last]

Comment: sorry missed to add the quotes  ```str="run -cmd 'list1' -cmd 'list2' -cmd 'list3' -cmd 'list4' -cmd 'list5' -cmd 'list6' -tail_cmd"```

Comment: This is very intersting: imagine list1 looks like `foo bar`, (i.e. have a space) this gets interesting.

Comment: Something like this will work: `$ eval "a=(" $str ")"` followed by `for i in $(seq 1 2 $((${#a[@]}-2))); do echo "${a[0]}" "${a[i]}" "${a[i+1]}" "${a[${#a[@]}-1]}"; done`

Comment: To generate the _required output_, we could just set the positional parameters and work through them in a loop:
```
eval set -- "$str";
run=$1; shift;
while [ $# -gt 2 ]; do echo $run $1 "$2" ${@: -1}; shift 2; done
```
Note that the quotes around _list_ will be removed, but the _special characters_ within correctly preserved.

Comment: thank you kvantour and armali for you valuable comments.